# Userfrosting installation issues

Tags: installation, userfrosting

I did installation of Userfrosting as per the steps - no errors and all went well (using ubuntu 16 command line).

When i loaded the site in browser, page did came but no CSS applied. Browser console said - failed to load resource. I checked and found that “asset-raw” folder is not there under userfrosting/public (this is my webroot).

Also when clicked on sign-in, it does not work. DO let me know if i missed anything.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache, you need to make sure Mod_Rewrite is enabled. `asset-raw` is not a real directory, it's an alias managed by the app.

See: https://learn.userfrosting.com/troubleshooting/common-problems#installation-went-fine-except-i-don-t-see-any-styling-on-my-home-page-i-am-using-apache-

Comment: Thanks for the details...I tried the steps given in the link

first enable the mod-rewrite, which gave me message as - Module rewrite already enabled

Then I also modified the apache2.conf file to - `Override All`

Restarted Apache - but still no luck. Anything else to be done?

Comment: Git it working, Apache was the issue. Thanks for your help.